# EXCEL VBA: Dot Product using Arrays

Tags: excel, vba, matrix, vector, linear-algebra

Below is example code which is an excerpt from a larger whole. I am attempting to compute the dot product of vectors `beta` and `Xtempj` which should be a scalar and then to multiple the resulting scalar by another scalar, `Ycoded(j,1)`.

However, I am receiving an error message "Type mismatch" during the assignment statement for `temp1(j,1)`.

Option Explicit

```
Sub XX()

    Dim beta As Variant
    Dim temp1 As Variant
    Dim X5 As Variant
    Dim Xtempj As Variant
    Dim Ycoded As Variant

    ReDim beta(1 To 2, 1 To 1)
    ReDim X5(1 To 2, 1 To 2)
    ReDim temp1(1 To 2, 1 To 1)
    ReDim Xtempj(1 To 2, 1 To 1)
    ReDim Ycoded(1 To 2, 1 To 1)

    beta(1, 1) = 0.510825624
    beta(2, 1) = 0

    X5(1, 1) = 1
    X5(1, 2) = 45
    X5(2, 1) = 1
    X5(2, 2) = 76

    Ycoded(1, 1) = 1
    Ycoded(2, 1) = 0

    For j = 1 To 2
        For k = 1 To 2
            Xtempj(k, 1) = X5(j, k)
        Next k

        temp1(j, 1) = WorksheetFunction.MMult(Application.Transpose(beta), Xtempj) * Ycoded(j, 1)

    Next j

End Sub
```

This error message makes me think that VBA is thinking of `Ycoded(j,1)` as a 1 x 1 array. Therefore, I also tried the following statement:

```
temp1(j, 1) = WorksheetFunction.MMult(WorksheetFunction.MMult(Application.Transpose(beta), Xtempj), Ycoded(j, 1))
```

However, here I receive the "Unable to get the MMult property of the WorksheetFunction class".

I can do this kind of thing in R or SAS Proc IML in my sleep, so this is VERY frustrating. Any assistance/insight is appreciated.

Best,

Dan

Comment: Please declare all your variables and what is X5k ? Put Option Explicit at the top of your module (always, everywhere)

Comment: X5k will potentially be initialised at variant/empty meaning your  For k = 1 To X5k doesn't happen and Xtempj won't be what you might have been expecting.

Comment: My apologies: That statement should read (for example purposes):                 
  For k = 1 To 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the partic instance shown, it is considered an array being returned and therefore is expecting you to index into that array e.g.

```
 temp1(j, 1) =  Ycoded(j, 1) * WorksheetFunction.MMult(Application.Transpose(beta), Xtempj)(1)
```

MMULT otherwise expects equal rows in one array to equal columns in the other array.

`WorksheetFunction.MMult(Application.Transpose(beta), Xtempj)` is producing a variant(1 to 1). You index into that with (1) to access the value.